# Rx Java Observable execute until some condition

Tags: java, android, promise, rx-java, future

I am trying to find a way to execute observable until some condition is met.

Consider the following example:

```
 myDelayedObservable = createListenerObserver();
    public Observable<Boolean> createListenerObserver() {

      // The part I am looking for
    }

    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listenerLayout = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
           myDelayedObservable.onCompleted();
         getTargetView().getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        }
    };

    public void performMultipleRequests() {

        Observable<Boolean> longRunningTask = Observable.zip(oneRequest, anotherRequest, myDelayedObservable,...);

    }
```

So the idea is to run multiple requests, for instance a download request, together with `myDelayedObservable` using `zip`, so `longRunningTask` completes only when all requests plus listener (in my case view finished layout) are completed.

But the problem is, I cannot find the right way to create my Observable for listener. It is like a barrier, so pseudo code

```
while(!viewIsLaidOut) {
  // just wait
}
observable.complete();
// After that `longRunningTask` should be completed
```

Please suggest the right way to achieve this, I have thought about `Future`, `Callable` but this seems to not be the best solution to me.

Comment: `myDelayedObservable` should it emit any values, or just complete without any `onNext`? Same question about `longRunningTask`. Do you actually use results from `oneRequest`, `anotherRequest`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, really it doesn't need to return any value, I need it just as a barrier, in order to be sure that everything has completed when my `longRunnningTask` completes.

Comment: Do you actually use results from `oneRequest`, `anotherRequest`?

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy no, I actually don't care about results. Only one thing is important is that multiple requests should be ziped, so I can know that everything is ready.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to `map` all observables to the same type, eg. `Observable<Boolean>`, so you can merge them:

```
observable1.map(String s -> "...".equals(s))
observable2.map(Integer i -> i > 0 && i < 100)
observable3.map(MyClass m -> true)
...
```

2) Use `Observable.merge()` to merge them all into single stream. **Using `zip` for this purpose will only work if all observables emit the same number of items**, otherwise it will complete as soon as the first one completes, without waiting for the rest.

```
Observable<Boolean> allInOne = Observable.merge(observable1, observable2, ...);
```

3) `myDelayedObservable` is just one of those observables that shall hold `allInOne` incomplete until some listener calls back. Use `Subject` for this purpose:

```
Subject<Boolean> myDelayedObservable = PublishSubject.create();
```

4) When your listener is ready, call `myDelayedObservable.onComplete()`.

5) Subscribe to `allInOne` and react on completion:

```
allInOne.subscribe(b -> { ... }, e -> { ... },
    () -> { ... go ahead with your next task ... });
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, so basically zip will always completes if any of observables completes ?

Comment: To add my tasks which are downloading dat from the net are related to the listener task, because download observables are triggering this listener.

Comment: @brqgddez regarding `zip`: not exactly. When it expects next value from you, but you *complete without value*, it completes immediately (also without value). Otherwise it will try to get corresponding values from other inputs, emit zipped value, then complete. Read the docs: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(rx.Observable,%20rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
PublishSubject<Boolean> myDelayedObservable = PublishSubject.create<>();
```

or for RxJava2

```
 PublishProcessor<Boolean> myDelayedObservable = PublishProcessor.create<>();
```

And when ready just call

```
 myDelayedObservable.onNext(true)
 //not this, myDelayedObservable.onComplete();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this looks similar to what I am looking for, but when I call  complete, it doesn't wait for another zipped observable to complete.

Comment: Did you try to call onNext instead? The onComplete would not do any emission and zip requires emissions to happen before it can collect work, hence onNext.